# ¿Se puede capturar el número de llamada en IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Buenas tardes,

Estoy con la creación de una app con la que puedas capturar el número de teléfono de llamada, en Android no parece muy difícil pero en IOS no encuentro la manera y hay foros que dicen que no se puede pero he visto que existe el CallKit pero que solo es para VoIp.

Bueno si alguien me pudiera arrojar luz sobre este tema se lo agradezco.

Un saludo.

Comment: no existen los permisos para capturar un numero telefónico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No existe ninguna API publica que permita obtener el número de teléfono de una llamada o del historial.

Existe una API privada para ello (https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/) pero no podrás publicar la aplicación en la App Store.